# Android Retrofit: I have four layered json format on webservice now i want to fetch those data in local

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, local-database

I am trying to retrieve it  Nd it's working but, not properly I mean that it's nested classes so i am totally confused with that please give me your best solution.
Firstly I want to save it in a local table then, it will show in the app.

Thanks!!

Trying to print values  in MainActivity this method been called in mainactivity

```java
    private void GetChildTitleLsit() {
        Call<MenuResponse> call = apiCallInterface.getResponseData("eyJhcGlrZXkiOiI1YTRmNzRiNTUyNzUxOWMwYzY3MGMwZWQ5MDRhZTM0MSJ9");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MenuResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MenuResponse> call, Response<MenuResponse> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: server response" + response.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: received info" + response.body());

                heroList = response.body().getData();
                retrofitAdapter = new RetrofitAdapter(getApplicationContext(), heroList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(retrofitAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MenuResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure something went wrong" + t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

These are the model classes I am using. I am confused when I want to print only specific values.

```java
Menuresponse class

    public class MenuResponse {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Datum> mData;

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

}
```

This Datum class

```java
    public class Datum {
    @SerializedName("childs")
    private List<Child> mChilds;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private Long mID;

    @SerializedName("menu_item_parent")
    private String mMenuItemParent;

    @SerializedName("object")
    private String mObject;

    @SerializedName("object_id")
    private String mObjectId;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String mTitle;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String mType;

    @SerializedName("url")
    private String mUrl;

    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return mChilds;
    }

}
```

And this is child class last one :

```java
    public class Child {
    @SerializedName("childs")
    private List<Child> mChilds;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private Long mID;

    @SerializedName("menu_item_parent")
    private String mMenuItemParent;

    @SerializedName("object")
    private String mObject;

    @SerializedName("object_id")
    private String mObjectId;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String mTitle;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String mType;

    @SerializedName("url")
    private String mUrl;

    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return mChilds;
    }
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Hello @DeepakRor i have uploaded code please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

To create the correct classes and class structure use this website: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Use Postman to get the response data. Then just post the Json into the website and it will generate the correct classes for you.

Select at Source type: JSON Schema

and Annonation style: Gson

Comment: hello, sir that's not issue i have already done these steps have already generated model classes using plugin called json2pojo in android studio Nd do installed postman and all that stuff

Comment: i am retrieving data but i think not in right formated then i do wanna save those data to loal table first

Comment: Use Room Database for local storage. You will be able to turn your data into a SQL Database and use SQL querys to retrieve/save data.

Comment: but now i am stuck at retrieving data i am getting response from server also able to retrieve data which is only root i have four layered json objects i wanna get only specific data only there i am stuck totally can you please show me how to do that

Comment: or please give some example for a specific item so I can get the overall idea so I can do further work on my own

Comment: You wont be able to learn on how to implement Room Database this quick. Find resources on the internet on how to do it.

Comment: Sir, i have made prototype to learn room database i had made an application which takes notes and can update the note basically performed CRUD operation

Comment: i want to know how to retrieve specific data  can show me by an example ??? i retrieved the data but only able to get root data i want each and every in recycler view atleast for now just wants to get child data there's four-layered nested object i am confused there